# What is the difference between an expression and a statement in Java?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner for Java, and I want to know the difference between expressions and statements in Java?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

Comment: These definitions are not language-specific in any way. If you get them once - you get them for good.

Comment: I think part of the problem is if you're looking at the java tutorial docs, they use a bunch of statements as examples of expressions. 
`int cadence = 0;`,  `anArray[0] = 100;`, etc... these are also statments.  Yes, all statements are made up of expressions, but its a little confusing to use them as the examples.

Comment: Look here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Expression
for in-depth understanding

Comment: Java 12 introduced switch **expressions** which is an improvement over the classic switch-case **statements**.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is an example :

`b + 1` is an expression while `a = b + 1;` is a statement. A statement consists of expressions.

This is not specific to the Java language. Many languages use this kind of grammar e.g. `C, C++, Basic` etc (not `SQL`).

Comment: And `a++` is an expression statement...

Comment: `a++` is an expression. `a++;` is an expression statement. See the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8)

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Thanks for pointing that out. I was just trying to give a simple example.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I think part of the problem where people are getting tripped up  is if they're looking at the java tutorial docs, they use a bunch of statements as examples for expressions. 
`int cadence = 0;`,  `anArray[0] = 100;`, etc... these are also statments.  Yes, all statements are made up of expressions, but its a little confusing to use them as the examples of ['Expressions you've already seen''](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

Comment: An expression is anything that evaluate to a value, a statement is composed of zero or more expressions.  check all the definitions here https://tutoref.com/java-expressions-statements-and-blocks/

Comment: RIP @PatriciaShanahan, https://www.apache.org/memorials/patricia_shanahan.html

Answer (score 32):

From Javadoc,

***Expression***

> An **expression** is a construct made up of variables, operators, and
> method invocations, which are constructed according to the syntax of
> the language, that evaluates to a single value.

For example,

> int **cadence** = 0;
>
> The data type of the value returned by an expression depends on the
> elements used in the expression. The expression `cadence = 0` returns an
> `int` because the `assignment` operator returns a value of the same data
> type as its left-hand operand; in this case, `cadence` is an `int`.

***Statement***

> **Statements** are roughly equivalent to sentences in natural languages. A
> statement forms a **complete** *unit of execution*.

Comment: Yes, this is straight from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html), but isn't clear enough the difference made.  They use the example  `int cadence = 0;` is an expression.  Then down a bit they use this as an example of a statement is `aValue = 8933.234;` . Why is one a statement and the other an expression?  Are they both expressions? Are they both also statements?  If not, what makes one a statement and/or an expression (as far as I can tell, they're both expressions and statements).

Comment: @Ray The docs don't claim `int cadence = 0;` is an expression. They claim that `cadence = 0` is an expression. Because `cadence = 0` isn't  a complete unit of execution without the semicolon. In the same way `aValue = 8933.234` is an expression within the statement of `aValue = 8933.234;`

Comment: @Backwardsman reviewing again I see your point.  The issue is the "bolded" part is the expression.  However, the font they're using doesn't visually differ enough that `int` and `cadence = 0` look clearly any different in my browser until I zoom in far enough--I thought everything in that block was bolded.

Comment: @Ray furthermore, `int cadence = 0;` is not an expression; it's a statement. `0` is an expression within that statement. `aValue = 8933.234;` is a statement and `aValue = 8933.234` is an expression within that statement.

Comment: Thank you @Kröw and @Backwardsman. For total, complete, exhaustive clarity, would we agree all of  the following correct:  `0` is an expression, `cadence = 0` is an expression, `int cadence` is a declaration, `int cadence = 0;` is a statement,  `int cadence;` is a statement, and  `cadence = 0;` is a statement?

Comment: @Ray I'd agree on just about all of that. I think the statement `int cadence = 0;` is also a declaration (a "declaration statement") but I'm not sure if `int cadence` qualifies as a declaration. Other than that, yes I agree!