# Why are "statements" needed in java when we have expressions?

Tags: java, expression

I recently was reading about expressions and statements, and I couldn't understand the need of statements. They are basically a bunch of expressions.

I have looked into and read some blog posts and other stuff [here](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/expressions-statements-blocks), [here](https://www.quora.com/What%E2%80%99s-the-difference-between-the-expressions-and-statements-in-Java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39523498/9264311), but I don't really understand why we need statements.

So if I do something like:

```
i++;
```

that is an expression-statement

```
int i = 0;
int i = 7 + 5;
```

are statements and

```
int i = 0
```

is an expression

So if statements are multiple expressions, and expressions are the most basic representation of the code that can be evaluated by the compiler, why do we need statements?

Comment: It's not python, every language has it's own syntax.

Comment: `int i;` is a declaration statement, not an expression.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks @khelwood. I thought that was an expression. I'll amend the question

Comment: Also `if/for/do/while/try/synchronized/{}/;`.

Comment: "int i = 0" would not be either. "i = 0" would be an expression (a construct that evaluates into a single value), "i = 0;" would be a statement (a unit of execution).

Comment: isn't ```i=0;``` an expression statement, @Torben, while```i=0``` is an expression?

Comment: @Pr Expression is a construct that evaluates into a single result. "i=0;" does not result in a value that you could assign anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algol 68 is such a high level expression language:

```
IF a < b THEN head ELSE current.next FI := c
```

This will conditionally assign to different variables, and the resulting expression is, say, `c`.

Statement are a feature of procedural languages, of having an effect and not persé resulting in a value.

Java chose for the (mixed) procedural paradigm, following in that respect (and relating the syntax) C++.

With lambdas at some places Java looks more like an expression language, though it will never be a pure EL, having many peculiar exceptional syntax rules, and not everything being able to be used as expression. However C++ is still worse IMHO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info!