# For loop without initialisation

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to know why I cant use a for loop with a pre-defined variable in java.

I tried googling it multiple times and all I can find is for loops without initializing variables at all, basically people explaining how this would be possible: for(;;) but that only creates a while loop.

```
int x = 0;   
for (x; x < 5; x++) {

}
```

The above code just gives the error message "not a statement". It requires me to instead write:

```
int x = 0;   
for (int i = x; i < 5; i++) { 

}
```

why cant I use a variable in a for loop?

Comment: `x` isn't a statement. Just do `for(; x < 5; x++)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Globgett pointed out a in a comment, what you want to do can be achieved using

```
int x = 0;   
for (; x < 5; x++) {

}
```

The compiler is complaining because in `for(A; B; C)`, `A` and `C` must be *statements*, and `B` must be a boolean *expression*. Your `A` is just `x`, which is an expression, but not a statement.

See here for more on the difference between statements and expressions: [What is the difference between an expression and a statement in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39523474/what-is-the-difference-between-an-expression-and-a-statement-in-java)

Answer (score 5):

it's about syntax itself it's expected three sections separated by comma and if don't want to initialize then you can declare it as follows

here you inform compiler to ignore initialization section from loop

```
int x =0;        
    for(;x<10;x++){
      System.out.println(x);
    }
```

you can also ignore stop condition and on this case it will go in infinte loop if you don't add stop condition

```
int x =0;
        for(;;x++){
          System.out.println(x);
          //stoping condition
          if(x>9){
            break;
          }

        }
```

Same for the third part of loop

```
int x =0;
for(;;){
  System.out.println(x);
  //stoping condition
  if(x>9){
    break;
  }
  x++;      
}
```

Comment: So the third one is exactly the same as `while true`? Why not just use `while true` as it's more common and probably easier to understand? I see it in production code here https://github.com/qcri/solr-6/blob/40fde37bb9291213149b93c08f1c4f12db340dd9/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/index/SegmentInfos.java#L670

Answer (score 2):

You can use pre-defined variable, but you shouldn't use `x` in the loop.

```
int x = 0;
for ( ; x < 5; x++) { 
   // your code
}
```

Comment: did you mean the first line to be int i = 0;

Comment: @Will yes, thanks. I corrected my answer

Comment: "you shouldn't use x in the loop" - what? I know what you meant, but it's not what you said.

Answer (score 1):

In your first attempt – `for (x; x < 5; x++)` – you are attempting to use `x` as the initialization statement, which is not valid.

Here is specific detail for creating a valid initialization statement (from [Chapter 14. Blocks and Statements -
14.14.1.1. Initialization of for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-ForInit)
):

> A for statement is executed by first executing the ForInit code:
>
> - If the ForInit code is a list of statement expressions (§14.8), the expressions are evaluated in sequence from left to right; their values, if any, are discarded.
> - If evaluation of any expression completes abruptly for some reason, the for statement completes abruptly for the same reason; any ForInit statement expressions to the right of the one that completed abruptly are not evaluated.
> - If the ForInit code is a local variable declaration (§14.4), it is executed as if it were a local variable declaration statement appearing in a block.
> - If execution of the local variable declaration completes abruptly for any reason, the for statement completes abruptly for the same reason.
> - If the ForInit part is not present, no action is taken.

Comment: The links to further reading are ok, however they sometimes stop working, therefore you should still briefly explain it in your answer. Also, your answer on its own doesn't show OP how to achieve what they are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just edited the post to include the relevant section from the linked Oracle doc.